# SwiftData doesn't persist data

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to build a macro tracker app but when i edit my data it never saves

```
@main
struct Macro_TrackerApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Macros.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabBarView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}
```

```
@Model
class Macros: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var date: Date
    var fat: CGFloat
    var carbs: CGFloat
    var proteins: CGFloat
    var calories: CGFloat
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, date: Date, fat: CGFloat, carbs: CGFloat, proteins: CGFloat, calories: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.fat = fat
        self.carbs = carbs
        self.proteins = proteins
        self.calories = calories
    }
}
```

```
func updateMacros(dailyMacros: Macros) {
        dailyMacros.fat += quickAddFat
        dailyMacros.carbs += quickAddCarbs
        dailyMacros.proteins += quickAddProteins
        dailyMacros.calories += ((quickAddFat * 9) + (quickAddCarbs * 4) + (quickAddProteins * 4))
    }
```

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query var macros: [Macros]
var dailyMacros: Macros? {
    macros.first(where: { Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, equalTo: Date.now, toGranularity: .day) }) ?? nil
}
```

```
HStack {
                    CustomButtonView(action: {
                        viewModel.updateMacros(dailyMacros: dailyMacros)
                        print(dailyMacros.carbs)
                        print(macros.first(where: { Calendar.current.isDate($0.date, equalTo: Date.now, toGranularity: .day) })?.carbs)
                    }, label: "Appliquer", color: Color.macroTrackerButton, width: 200, height: 50)
                }
```

I call this function if i my Query return an empty array

```
func insert() {
        modelContext.insert(Macros(date: Date.now, fat: 0, carbs: 0, proteins: 0))
    }
```

i can't understand, i only see todo app tutorials so it does not really help me thanks !

i tried saving manually but nothing change, i tried to print my var data just to know if it's well edited and yes.. So i don't understand why everytime i kill the app all my objects return to inital state, they are not deleted but i can't edit them, it does not save

here is the repo : https://github.com/Killianoni/Macro-Tracker

Comment: Lot's of information missing, how do you initially create and insert your Macros objects, how do you call the updateMacros function? We don't see anything of the workflow of your app.

Comment: I edited my post sorry i only succeeded to work with SwiftData with Lists and ForEach but here i want to show one View corresponding to the current date so i don't initially start with a list or forEach, tell me if you are missing some other informations

Comment: There’s still no information on how you create your objects.

Comment: You are right i'm sorry i edited the post

Comment: After updating the information in an object you will also need to call `context.save()` to actually store the new information.

Comment: Tbh i already did it and it change nothing, actually we don't even need to call it it's automatically saved with SwiftData, but i tried it

Comment: I don't understand what is going on here but it seems to me after reproducing this that auto saving doesn't work as expected. I would call  modelContext.save() directly after the update function.

Comment: Unrelated but CGFloat is a type from Core Graphics and there is no reason to use it here even if it only is a type alias for Double. Use basic types like Double instead, it's more appropriate and less confusing

Comment: Thanks ! I linked the project it may be easier for y'all, don't mind DataSource, i tried a lot of things, i don't use it anymore i'll update all when the solution will be found

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SwiftData, all the changes made in the UI is saved properly which can be verified either by restarting the app or activating debug logging for Core Data

You can do this by going to Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Arguments and add

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

The actual issue with your code is in the views, first the view model in the `DiaryView` should be declared as a `@StateObject` since it's owned by the view

```
@StateObject var viewModel = DiaryViewModel()
```

Then in `ProgressCircleView` we have the opposite problem, the property `number1` is not owned by the view nor changed by it so it is not a `@State` property so change it and the others to `let` instead apart from the optional one.

```
let number1: CGFloat
let number2: CGFloat
let color: Color
let size: CGFloat
var title: String?
```

With those changes your UI should be updated properly.

Comment: I added all your changes but it still reset my values when i relaunch the app, but it does not delete my objects it just don't save i push it on the repo

Comment: I used the project you linked to on GitHub, I can't understand how we can get different results?

Comment: I re-downloaded the project with your updates and to me it works as expected.

Comment: Did u try it on a simulator ? Because on mine every restart resets the data ? Maybe i have a problem with my container in my Xcode config ? Do you have some things that i can be missing ?

Comment: Yes a simulator. Maybe try and download the project into a new folder and run a clean version.

Comment: I cleaned all with a new install on a new device but i still have no data saves all my infos are sets to 0 can u provide maybe a video or i something showing your config i'm losing hope

Comment: Hey just to let you know I recreated the whole project by adding manually the old files one by one and it finally work, so I have no idea why it didn't didn't work it may be an Xcode configuration issue. Thanks